# Why doesn't my Javascript menu trapping work when last item is a dual-purpose item and parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I have a pop-out navigation menu that appears on smaller screens when an 'open menu' button is clicked, tapped or keyed with enter or spacebar. (Javascript, CSS and HTML; no jQuery).

The navigation uses divs, rather than an unordered list, with a `<nav>` container but the problem outlined below happens whether the menu is in divs or an unordered list.

If a keyboard user is tabbing, opens the pop-out, continues tabbing, the user is cycled round the trapped area until either a navigation link is opened with the enter/spacebar keys or the pop-out is closed by using the enter/spacebar on the 'close button' or the Escape key is pressed (with thanks to Graham Ritchie for this code).

It works fine in general. See this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Scrabble96/pen/vYyWWKj) that works.

BUT, if the last item in the menu is both a direct link and a parent with a sub-menu, then the trapping does not work and anyone tabbing in the pop-out menu finds themselves in the browser's address bar area outside the website itself or, in the case of this [Codepen where it is not working correctly](https://codepen.io/Scrabble96/pen/abBVVaV), the tabbing moves down to the 'Console, Assets, Comments...' area at the bottom of the browser.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what I need to do to resolve it? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Gillian, sorry I have not come back to yet, had a lot going on, I have looked at it for you though. The reason it doesn't work is that the script will pick up hidden elements. One thing it does to trap focus is to look for the last item in the menu and then put focus back to the first item in the menu. Because the last item in the menu is hidden it never gets there (but the script still discovers it) and so it does not trigger. A fix is to account for hidden items and I will eventually respond with a fix if nobody else can help you!

Comment: Thanks, Graham. The last item is a sub-menu which is hidden but the sibling button that opens it is not, so some kind of code to work on that combination would do the trick.

Comment: The issue comes when you open the item it needs to recalculate the last item that can receive focus, so it is easier to do a calculation on all the items that can receive focus to see if they are indeed visible and usable. Otherwise you wouldn't me able to tab into the sub menu!

Comment: I can add a special class to the button or submenu if it appears in that position, if that helps.